# What does the Middle Man say in Hebrew?

Tags: comics, the-middleman

In the Middle Man comic, the Entering Dragon Conundrum, the Middle Man claims to be Mossad but is casually "tested" by a museum curator by speaking Hebrew to him.  The Middle Man's response leaves the curator gulping.  I was wondering what they say to each other?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are you a product of the kibbutz movement like me?

> Once, another fellow asked me the same question. [I kicked] his genitals into his watch-pocket. Now he needs to check the time every time he wishes to copulate.

(The word for *I kicked* is missing a letter.)

Comment: This drive-by answer is thanks to [Gilles](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4994520#4994520).

Comment: Note that in addition to the missing letter, the text itself is rather badly phrased. There's a place where the wrong gender is used for a word ("אותו השאלה" rather than "אותה השאלה") and the terms used feel stilted and awkward in colloquial Hebrew ("watch pocket" is even more archaic than in English, for instance).
In short, it doesn't feel like a sentence that a native Hebrew speaker would say. I don't know whether this is appropriate for the character, or just bad research.

Comment: I am glad they used a reasonable Hebrew font though. Too often when fragments of Hebrew are used in comics or other mediums, they use extremely elaborate biblical-looking fonts.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I'm gonna turn my comment into an answer, since it's probably the closest thing there is to an "official" translation.

The equivalent scene in the TV show is subtitled:

> **Curator**: Are you a product of the kibbutz movement like me?
>
> **The Middleman**: A man asked me that question once. I kicked his male reproductive organs into his watch pocket. Now he must check the time whenever he wishes to copulate.

I don't speak Hebrew, but this is close enough to msh210's answer that it seems pretty safe to assume it's the same dialogue...